# Android in-app billing signature verification in php server

Tags: php, android, in-app-billing, public-key-encryption

I am working on the IAB v3 in my android application.
After every succes purchase, I want my app to send back the sign data and signature to my php server for verification by the public key generated by google developer console.
I found the following code.

```
<?php
// $data and $signature are assumed to contain the data and the signature

// fetch public key from certificate and ready it
$fp = fopen("/src/openssl-0.9.6/demos/sign/cert.pem", "r");
$cert = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);
$pubkeyid = openssl_get_publickey($cert);

// state whether signature is okay or not
$ok = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $pubkeyid);
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "good";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad";
} else {
    echo "ugly, error checking signature";
}
// free the key from memory
openssl_free_key($pubkeyid);
?>
```

Now I have a problem. The public key given by google is in String Base64 Encoded. I do not know how to convert that string key to a ".pem" format.

If I put my Base64 Encoded key to "$pubkeyid" on the above code. A warning will be given.

`Warning: openssl_verify() [function.openssl-verify]: supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key in myxxx.php.`

How can I convert my String Base64 Encoded public key to the php accept format ?

Do anyone have the above experience or solution? Please help. Many thanks.

Comment: `base64_decode(...)` is your friend....

Comment: Although the key can be decoded by base64_decode(), openssl_verify() still warns my $pubkeyid is in wrong format. What should I do?

`openssl_verify() [<a href='function.openssl-verify'>function.openssl-verify</a>]: supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key`

Answer (score 9):

To convert the long base64-encoded public key you get from Google into one that you can use in PHP, try this:

```
$base64EncodedPublicKeyFromGoogle = "..."; // This is the public key for your app you get from Google.

$openSslFriendlyKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" . chunk_split($base64EncodedPublicKeyFromGoogle, 64, "\n") .  "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

Then you can pass that into `openssl_get_publickey()`.

```
$publicKeyId = openssl_get_publickey($openSslFriendlyKey);
```

As you can see, the format from Google is almost the right kind. It just needs to be broken up into 64-character lines, and prepended/appended with the right header/footer.

You can also use the OpenSSL command to convert the public key like this:

```
openssl enc -base64 -d -in publickey.base64 -A | openssl rsa -inform DER -pubin > publickey.pem
```

Then you can read in the generated `publickey.pem` file with PHP and pass its contents to the `openssl_get_publickey()` function.

Comment: This should be part of the Google guide to verifying signature. Hours of searching for the correct structure of a public key to use... Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line, how can I solve?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was fixed by this API.

https://github.com/mgoldsborough/google-play-in-app-billing-verification

Comment: The above php class doesn't work anymore, any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

A complete solution to the poster's question:

```
<?php
// $data and $signature are assumed to contain the data and the signature

// Paste your google public key below:
$base64EncodedPublicKeyFromGoogle  = "###############################"

//Convert the key to the right format for open SSL
$openSslFriendlyKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" . chunk_split($base64EncodedPublicKeyFromGoogle, 64, "\n") .  "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
$publicKeyId = openssl_get_publickey($openSslFriendlyKey);

// free the key from memory
openssl_free_key($publicKeyId);

//Perform signature verification. Don't forget to decode the signature!
$ok = openssl_verify($data, base64_decode($signature), $publicKeyId, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "good";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad";
} else {
    echo openssl_error_string();
}

?>
```